# How to format eMMC on beaglebone black?

Tags: beagleboneblack

I came across with a problem these days!

The problem is that after I writing debian os from microSD card to emmc, beaglebone clould i9 says:

```
Failed to write to 'state.settings'. ENOSPC: no space left on device, write
```

and nothing works at all!

So I decide to format the emmc on beaglebone!

Can anyone help me how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the wrong debian version. Currently (12.03.2020) the version "Debian 9.9 2019-08-03 4GB SD IoT" is just usable for microSD card and is not recommended for eMMC flashing. If you want to flash the eMMC you can currently use the version "Debian 9.5 2018-10-07 4GB eMMC IoT Flasher". Unfortunatley, does this version not include the graphical desktop.